# Dual statement in triangulated category

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, triangulated-categories

I want to show that if $X \overset{f}{\rightarrow} Y \overset{g}{\rightarrow} Z \overset{h}{\rightarrow} X[1]$ and $h = 0$ then $f$ is a split monomorphism and $g$ is a split epimorphism. I have proved that $f$ must be split mono.

My intuition tells me that showing that $g$ is a split epimorphism would be the dual statement, but I am not really sure. My idea is that considering the opposite category, i.e. reversing the arrows, and rotating the triangle, I would get the following distinguished triangle in the opposite category

$$
Z \overset{g}{\rightarrow} Y \overset{f}{\rightarrow} X \overset{h}{\rightarrow} Z[-1]
$$

Agein $h$ would be the zero morphism, so $g$ would be split mono in the opposite category, hence a split epi in the original category.

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, however, you should draw the arrows in the opposite direction.

There is only one concern, you must ensure that the snake does not bite his own tail; here you use the fact that if $X \to Y \to Z \to X[1]$ is a triangle, then $Z[-1]\to X \to Y \to Z$ is also a triangle. Depending on your reference, you may or may not have proven that here. This is ok if you already know that $[-1]$ is an equivalence of triangulated categories.

Otherwise, just use the functor $\hom(Z,-)$ which is cohomological on your triangle and you have the answer:
You get a long exact sequence
$$\hom(Z,X) \to \hom(Z,Y) \to \hom(Z,Z) \to \hom(Z,Z[1])$$
where the last arrow is $h_*=0$, which means $g_*$ is surjective and there exists $s \in \hom(Z,Y)$ such that $g_* (s) = 1_Z$, i.e. $gs=1_Z$. The converse is obvious